# Select Earliest Date from List of Distinct Employee numbers

Tags: sql, join, group-by

```
SELECT 
    a1.[employee_number], 
    a1.[class_id], 
    a1.[TraineeAddedOn],
    a1.[TraineeRemovedOn], 
    a1.[effective_start_date], 
    a2.REHIRE
FROM TrainingAnalytics_Staging..VW_FACT_TRAINING_USER_INFO a1
LEFT JOIN DW..[VW_DIM_EMPLOYEE_DETAIL] a2 ON a1.employee_number = a2.employee_number
GROUP BY a1.class_id
HAVING MIN(a1.TraineeAddedOn)
```

I'm using this query but getting this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near ')'.

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY/HAVING. Do ORDER BY and TOP 1.

Comment: That would be `HAVING MIN(a1.TraineeAddedOn)`.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and some explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: hi team. Thanks for your response. What im trynna get is,

emp_no     |     start_date
1234          |     11/2/2019
1234          |     11/1/2019
1234          |     11/3/2019

query output should be
emp_no     |     start_date
1234          |     11/1/2019

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
   SELECT Top 1 a1.[employee_number], a1.[class_id], a1.[TraineeAddedOn],
           a1.[TraineeRemovedOn], a1.[effective_start_date], a2.REHIRE
    FROM TrainingAnalytics_Staging..VW_FACT_TRAINING_USER_INFO a1
    LEFT JOIN
            DW..[VW_DIM_EMPLOYEE_DETAIL] a2
        ON a1.employee_number = a2.employee_number
    ORDER BY a1.TraineeAddedOn
```

Comment: hi team. Thanks for your response. What im trynna get is, 
 
employee_number traineeaddedon
12345 11/6/2019
12345 11/1/2019
12345 11/2/2019
41523 10/8/2019
41523 10/5/2019
41523 10/19/2019
 
 
output 
 
employee_number traineeaddedon
12345 11/1/2019
41523 10/5/2019

Comment: @xivxiv Not getting exact idea what you want in your result. Please make somewhat easy to understand so others can answer it and helpout to you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to get the min TraineeAddedOn for each employee?
I think something like this would do:

```
-- First get list of min date per employee
With MinDatePerEmploye AS 
(
SELECT employee_number, MIN(TraineeAddedOn) AS MinTraineeAddedOn
FROM TrainingAnalytics_Staging..VW_FACT_TRAINING_USER_INFO
GROUP BY employee_number
)
-- and now join that up with rest of dataset
SELECT 
    a1.[employee_number], 
    a1.MinTraineeAddedOn,
    a2.[class_id], 
    a2.[TraineeAddedOn],
    a2.[TraineeRemovedOn], 
    a2.[effective_start_date], 
    a2.REHIRE
FROM MinDatePerEmploye a1
INNER JOIN TrainingAnalytics_Staging..VW_FACT_TRAINING_USER_INFO a2
ON a1.employee_number = a2.employee_number AND a1.MinTraineeAddedOn = a2.TraineeAddedOn
```